# How to convert sql.date to util.date so that i can set that date to JDateChooser?

Tags: java, sqlite, java.util.date, jdatechooser, sqldatetime

I'm trying to convert sql.date which i'm getting from my sqlite database to util.date. And i want to set that date to JDateChooser.
I've literally tried all possible ways but it seems i'm missing something. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
try{
    String query = "select * from SkaterInfo where reg_no = ?";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setInt(1, num1);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
         name = rs.getString("Name");
         surname = rs.getString("Surname");
         batch = rs.getInt("Batch");
         cell = rs.getLong("Mobile_No");
         date = rs.getDate("Birth_Date");
    }


    pst.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(Exception a){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception");
}

java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
dateChooser.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 30);
dateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateChooser.setDate(date1);
frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: yeah,, kind of.. actually not errors,, lots of exceptions..:p

Comment: Include the exceptions in your post, to give us a hint. They should come from the code you posted.

Comment: to be more specific it is giving me NullPointerException.

Comment: Then I would say you get the nullpointer because you don't  have a date. Add a check before to see if your java.sql.date is null or not. (If it is null you can not convert it...)

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm new to java.. :| so can you tell me how to check it? should i try if else? n yes then where.

Comment: And bdw how could it be null if I'm accessing it from my database?

Comment: Because it is `null` in the database, or because there are no records with that `reg_no` in the database.

Comment: Question: Given that `rs.getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date` object for the `date` variable, why are you converting that `java.sql.Date` to another `java.sql.Date` object for the `date1` variable, when your title says you want a `java.util.Date` object? BTW: Conversion is unnecessary, because a `java.sql.Date` object *is* a `java.util.Date` object.

Comment: yeah right, i should convert it to java.util.Date. So i tried that too. But still not working. And I've checked the database too, it has Date entry. And if conversion is not necessary, it should be easy to set date by just passing sql date to JDateChooser, but it's not working either

Comment: If possible just tell me how should i set date retrieved from database to JDateChooser.

Comment: @ParagPawar "It's not working" "I have a NullPointerException" is not really helpful. Unless you post a stacktrace, which points to a specific line of code, it's going to be nothing more than guessing. A good first step would be to avoid "swallowing" exceptions like you do in the catch block. Print the stack trace instead, it will give you a lot of valuable information. And read the first few answers of the duplicate to understand how to debug a NullPointerException.

Comment: As i said earlier, i'm still new to java and i'm still learning. But thanks :) I'll try to improve.. :)